# How can i make string one column to three columns with bash?

Tags: linux, command-line

```
P1 
-9.76033960E-01 
-1.46731660E+00 
-1.46731660E+00 
P2 
+6.06731500E-03 
-9.75908860E-01 
-1.46694710E+00 
P3 
+5.34414000E-03
-8.65252120E-01 
-1.30036450E+00
```

Result:

```
P1                P2                P3
-9.76033960E-01   +6.06731500E-03   +5.34414000E-03 
-1.46731660E+00   -9.75908860E-01   -8.65252120E-01 
-1.46731660E+00   -1.46694710E+00   -1.30036450E+00
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it in three files, for examle, using `split -l NUMBER`, and then use `paste`  command.

Comment: P1,P2 and P3 not match in columns, please advice.

Comment: do you mean the columns may have different number of rows?